# Is the ternary operator cache unfriendly?

Tags: c++, c, caching, gcc, ternary-operator

While playing around with a cache simulator (which compiles code with gcc and -O3 before creating a memory trace) an interesting thing happened.

Following code: `a[i] = min(a[i], b[j])` results in 4 memory accesses if `min` is defined as a ternary operator macro: `min(x, y) (((x) < (y)) ? (x) : (y))` and in 3 memory accesses if `min` is defined as `if (a < b) then a else b`.

Apparently, the simulator fetches all variables in the macro (even the one in the branch not taken) while `if-else` doesn't do this. Is this just a simulator intrinsic thing/bug, or a real issue with ternary operators?

Comment: I would think that the answer to that would be entirely dependent on which compiler you use, and possibly the optimization level you are using with it.

Comment: What is `then`?  Since when does an `if` statement produce a value as if it were an expression?

Comment: my version of gcc (as expected) produces exactly the same code for both versions - assuming my intuitive reading of correct `if` version.

Comment: At `-O3`, GCC produces [similar code](https://godbolt.org/g/ndj4Pi) for both constructions on x86.

Comment: Surely only 2 memory accesses are required when cached / optimised? `x` and `y` are both needed for the comparison...

Comment: suggest posting the true code for "min is defined as `if (a < b) then a else b`"

Comment: @John Bollinger. If is just the simplified min function: if (a<b) return a; else return b;

Comment: Please pick one of C and C++ for this question. C and C++ are different languages and differ in their semantic!

Comment: @PavleDjordjevic, `if (a<b) return a; else return b;` is not a good substitute for `(((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. If you have a full example that illustrates a difference, that would be helpful. As such, the answers provided just basically dispute your premise.

Comment: @PavleDjordjevic You should mention which cache simulator so that someone familiar with it could give you a definitive answer rather than speculative.

Answer (score 5):

It really depends on the compiler vendor. However, considering the following two versions of `min(int, int)`:

```
int min(int a, int b) {
  return (a < b)? a : b;
}

int min(int a, int b) {
  if(a < b)
    return a;
  else
    return b;
}
```

The assembly code produced for them by GCC version 5.3 and Clang version 3.8 with -O3 is the same:

```
min(int, int):
        cmpl    %esi, %edi
        movl    %esi, %eax
        cmovle  %edi, %eax
        ret
```

[**GCC Live Demo**](https://godbolt.org/g/cbXsgR)

[**CLANG Live Demo**](https://godbolt.org/g/xYJl91)

Consequently, at least for the two main vendors the two versions (i.e., ternary operator and if-else) are equivalent.

Comment: Upvoted for actually checking the generated code with a few major compilers.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, uses of the ternary operator and if-then-else statements result in the same intermediate representation in the compiler. Both do the same thing, both are equally cache-friendly.

I suspect that the difference comes from other things you changed between the two implementations, but without seeing them I can't tell you what the problem is.